# C# RijndaelEnhanced decrypt with php mcrypt

Tags: c#, php, rijndael

i have a C# .net app with i decompiled. Tis app uses for login password cryption:
http://www.obviex.com/samples/Sample.aspx?Source=EncryptionWithSaltCS&Title=Encryption%20With%20Salt&Lang=C%23

C# Code

```
rijndaelKey = new Krypto.RijndaelEnhanced(passPhrase, initVector);
PlainPassword = DiverseVariablen.rijndaelKey.Decrypt(Conversions.ToString(row["ProjectKennwort"])))
```

I have pass and iv.

How can i decrypt the passwords in php?
I tryted allready several variants of mcrypt_decrypt().

Didt somene have a idea?

Friendly regards and big thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they're using a [password-based key derivation function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2).  mycrypt gives you set the key directly and null pads it if appropriate.  The C# library you've linked to derives a password from the key.  A Google search for PBKDF2 PHP reveals the following:

htt­p://www.itnewb.com/v/Encrypting-Passwords-with-PHP-for-Storage-Using-the-RSA-PBKDF2-Standard

So I'd try that.  Also, I'd, personally, recommend using [phpseclib, a pure PHP AES implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/), for portability.  That PHP is installed on a server doesn't mean that mcrypt is.

Comment: Thanks of Answer: but it dont helps. I tryed it but it dint work. Whats me confuse is that the C# class needs a 16 chars IV with a 256 byte key. But a 256 byte key needs in php 32 chars iv.

Comment: You're still using mcrypt aren't you?  Like I said, I'd try phpseclib's Crypt_AES instead.  It's a lot easier to use.  mcrypt is usable enough too but it does things in confusing ways.  Like mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size(), iirc, always says 32, for AES.  That's because mcrypt implements Rijndael and not AES and Rijndael supports variable block sizes, the largest of which is 256 bits.  If you use a 128 bit key it should still work, despite what that function says.  Or you could just use phpseclib's Crypt_AES and eliminate the headache...